# SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'feature_item' & ''status' cannot be null

Tags: php, sql, arrays, laravel, forms

in my form when i checked the checkedbox there is no error .but when i don't want to check the  checkedbox, I am getting the error SQLSTATE[23000]:  1048 Column 'feature_item' & ''status' cannot be null.

**1.my products table:-**

```
public function up()
    {
      Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
           $table->increments('id');
           $table->integer('category_id');
           $table->string('product_name');
           $table->string('product_code');
           $table->string('product_color');
           $table->text('description'); 
           $table->boolean('feature_item')->default(0);
           $table->boolean('status')->default(0);
           $table->timestamps();
       });
   }
```

**2.my product.blade.php**
This is my form

```
<div class="control-group">
 <label class="control-label">Feature Item</label>
 <div class="controls">
 <input type="checkbox" name="feature_item" id="feature_item" value="1">
</div>
</div>


<div class="control-group">
<label class="control-label">Status</label>
<div class="controls">
<input type="checkbox" name="status" id="status" value="1">
</div>
</div>
```

**3.my ProductsController**

```
public function addproduct(Request $request){

         $product->category_id=$request['category_id'];
         $product->product_name=$request['product_name'];
         $product->product_code=$request['product_code'];
         $product->product_color=$request['product_color'];
         $product->description=$request['description'];
         $product->feature_item=$request['feature_item'];
         $product->status=$request['status'];

         if (!empty($request['description'])) {
             $product->description = $request['description'];
         } else {

             $product->description = '';
         }

         if(empty($request['feature_item'])){
             $feature_item='0';
         }else{
             $feature_item='1';
         }

         $product->status=$request['status'];
         if (empty($request['status'])) {
             $status = '0';
         } else {
             $status = '1';
         }

         $product->save();
         return back()->with('success','product Upload Successfully!');
         }
```

**This error I get:**

**SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'feature_item' & 'status' cannot be null**

Any help ps ?

Comment: If you would like to check this status, maybe if the checkbox is false you can put value equals 0 or false, according to your database column data type. Or remove the database restriction to not insert null values in listed columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your controller, you check if `status` and `feature_item` are empty but you don't define, what should be written to your model in that case, you're only assigning values to variables, that will never be used again.

To fix that, assign those values to the product properties to ensure, they get saved.

```
if (empty($request['feature_item'])){
    $product->feature_item = '0';
} else {
    $product->feature_item = '1';
}

if (empty($request['status'])) {
    $product->status = '0';
} else {
    $product->status = '1';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it is because of when you don't check the checkBoxes
nothing send to your controller with name `feature_item` & `status`
and then your method in controller try to insert `nothing` to `feature_item` & `status` in database
**Solutions**

## 1:

**Modify DATABASE**
you can modify table in database and set default value of `false` for `feature_item` & `status` fields;

## 2:

**check these two fields in controller like this**

```
if (empty($request['feature_item']))
    $product->feature_item = '0';
if (empty($request['status']))
    $product->status = '0';
```

Answer (score 0):

You add this two line

```
$product->feature_item=$feature_item;
$product->status=$status;
$product->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

`$product->feature_item=$request['feature_item'];`

before assignment check if

> $request['feature_item'];

is have some value or not, when you did not check the checkbox, $request['feature_item'] had no vale.
you have a conditional check, you may use that

```
  if(empty($request['feature_item'])){
             $feature_item='0';
         }else{
             $feature_item='1';
         }
```

To use this, remove

```
$product->feature_item=$request['feature_item'];
```

this line and add line

```
$product->feature_item= $feature_item;
```

So, it looks like

```
if(empty($request['feature_item'])){
                 $feature_item='0';
             }else{
                 $feature_item='1';
             }
$product->feature_item= $feature_item;
```

after your check of empty and before saving to the database. Do similar for **$request['status']**